# Automate monthly refresh to be current month instead of manually entering the fiscal range SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Current situation I have to at the end of every month change the fiscal period for example to 10 or 11 and next month i will have to change again. I know there is a way to just make it update every month to the current month based on todays date maybe using a Getdate() function? I just am not sure and am new sorry, I will submit my current code here

```
`SELECT sum([DEBIT_CREDIT_AMT_LOCAL_CURRENCY]*-1) as [DEBIT_CREDIT_AMT_LOCAL_CURRENCY],
   --[GL_ACCOUNT_NO],
       [POSTING_DT],
[FISCAL_PERIOD],
[FISCAL_YEAR]
--[COST_CENTER_CD] 
  FROM [EDWFIN].[dbo].[ACCOUNT_LEDGER_Vw]  
 where[FISCAL_YEAR]>='2020' and 
([FISCAL_PERIOD]='10' or [FISCAL_PERIOD]='11')
and[PROFIT_CENTER_CD]='104417'and GL_ACCOUNT_NO IN ('301000','301000','311000','342000')
group by [POSTING_DT], [FISCAL_PERIOD], [FISCAL_YEAR];
```

Now for the year to update as well, why is this not working? it doesnt give me an error, it runs, but it does not actually pull the current year, it is pulling all my years of data

```
 SELECT sum([DEBIT_CREDIT_AMT_LOCAL_CURRENCY]*-1) as [DEBIT_CREDIT_AMT_LOCAL_CURRENCY],
   --[GL_ACCOUNT_NO],
       [POSTING_DT],
[FISCAL_PERIOD],
[FISCAL_YEAR]
--[COST_CENTER_CD] 
  FROM [EDWFIN].[dbo].[ACCOUNT_LEDGER_Vw]  
 where[FISCAL_YEAR] = YEAR(GetDate()) and 
[FISCAL_PERIOD] = MONTH(GetDate()) -1 or [FISCAL_PERIOD] = MONTH(GetDate())
and[PROFIT_CENTER_CD]='104417'and GL_ACCOUNT_NO IN ('301000','301000','311000','342000')
group by [POSTING_DT], [FISCAL_PERIOD], [FISCAL_YEAR];
```

Comment: `[FISCAL_PERIOD] = MONTH(GetDate())`.  Side note: don't put single quotes around integer scalar values, it forces implicit data type conversion which slows your queries down.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the new information there.  It's not easy to read that in a comment.

Comment: Updated! Sorry.

Comment: The `(` at the beginning of the `[FISCAL_PERIOD = MONTH...` line is unclosed (there's no matching `)`.  Since everything in your WHERE clause uses AND you don't need them anyway.

Comment: `and ( [FISCAL_PERIOD] = MONTH(GetDate()) )`

Comment: @squillman Thank you a ton!

Comment: @squillman remember how my original had a range of prior and current month? Is it possible to make that update automatically as well? so like make it auto show month 10 till month 11 but update, instead of just the current month do current and prior? Sorry just wondering how to improve further!

Comment: Prior month is just `MONTH(GetDate()) - 1`, with the exception of course of January with which you have to inspect the year as well.

Comment: @squillman works like a charm! Thanks so much for taking time to help me!

Comment: Good deal, glad it's working.

Comment: @squillman sorry i just updated the question, one last thing, may be a simple thing i misplaced can you take a look? Please! It will be a great help my friend

Comment: I actually had to just add the ( and ) back to the start and end of the month sector of it

Answer (score 0):

Okay with the help of some very kind people on the comments here we got it working, here is the final code

```
 SELECT sum([DEBIT_CREDIT_AMT_LOCAL_CURRENCY]*-1) as [DEBIT_CREDIT_AMT_LOCAL_CURRENCY],
   --[GL_ACCOUNT_NO],
       [POSTING_DT],
[FISCAL_PERIOD],
[FISCAL_YEAR]
--[COST_CENTER_CD] 
  FROM [EDWFIN].[dbo].[ACCOUNT_LEDGER_Vw]  
 where [FISCAL_YEAR] = YEAR(GetDate()) and 
([FISCAL_PERIOD] = MONTH(GetDate()) -1 or [FISCAL_PERIOD] = MONTH(GetDate()))
and[PROFIT_CENTER_CD]='104417'and GL_ACCOUNT_NO IN ('301000','301000','311000','342000')
group by [POSTING_DT], [FISCAL_PERIOD], [FISCAL_YEAR];
```

Comment: For efficiency's sake, it's much better to not use `OR` predicates in the `WHERE`, instead use a range `([FISCAL_PERIOD] >= MONTH(GetDate()) -1 AND [FISCAL_PERIOD] <= MONTH(GetDate()))`